# Animação com Problema no Safari

Tags: css, less, css-animations

Há um tempo percebi que no Safari as animações funcionam de uma maneira diferente.

Por exemplo, se tivermos um texto dentro de um `span` e queremos que ao `hover` as letras desse texto diminuam `1px`, colocamos `letter-spacing: -1px;`. Colocando um `transition: all 0.5 ease;`, no **Chrome** e **Firefox** funcionam suavemente.

Mas no **Safari**, isso acontece abruptamente, ignorando a suavidade da transição. Por que ?

Porque eu não defini no elemento normal um `letter-spacing: 0px;`. Ou seja, é preciso que a propriedade esteja com um valor inicial para acontecer a transição. Apenas no **Safari** acontece isso.

Agora no caso abaixo não consigo contornar a situação. 
Ao entrar no site, duas imagens executam uma animação. Mas ao `hover` dessas imagens, acontece outro efeito.

Daí quando tira o mouse de cima da imagem, ela volta nas suas propriedades iniciais e não para as propriedades que defini no `100%` do `keyframes` da animação.

No **CSS** defini no elemento que a imagem vai começar com:

```
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(0);
```

E no **KeyFrame** defini que vai terminar com:

```
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
```

Daí no Safari a imagem volta com `opacity:0`...

### CSS

```
    .menu-language-full{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 15px;
        img{
            margin-left: 5px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0);
            animation-name: ShowImgIdioma;
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.27, 1.55);
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.6s ease;
            &.pt-br{
                animation-delay: 2.2s; 
            }
            &.en{
                animation-delay: 2.4s;
            }
            &:hover{
                transform: scale(1.1);
                filter: blur(1px);
            }
        }
    }
```

### KeyFrames

```
@keyframes ShowImgIdioma{
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: voce prefixou o `keyframe` ? se não me engano, essa é uma exigência do safari

Comment: Sim, prefiquissei.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ocorrer pelo browser não estar reconhecendo as propriedades css tente como o exemplo abaixo, que é um exemplo onde o mesmo é executado em todos navegadores.

//OPACITY

```
-moz-opacity: 0.28;
-khtml-opacity: 0.28;
opacity: 0.28;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=28);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=28);
filter:alpha(opacity=28);
```

//TRANSITION

```
-webkit-transition: all 01s ease;
-moz-transition: all 01s ease;
-ms-transition: all 01s ease;
-o-transition: all 01s ease;
transition: all 01s ease;
```

//TRANSFORM

```
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
```

Comment: O meu está assim Rodrigo. É que eu programo em LESS e depois compilo em CSS com o Gulp.Js. E ele faz esses prefixes automaticamente.